# SSIS Script transformation error CS0103 when using Output0Buffer class

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm trying to help our dba by supplying script written with c#, so he can use it in his ScriptComponent.

I have an input file, process it line by line and create a row in Output0Buffer as it is explained in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/441678/Getting-Started-With-SSIS-Script-transforms?fid=1765989&tid=4344144

I have written the test method and it works fine, however after inserting the logic inside of `Input0_ProcessInputRow` method as it's shown in the example, we are getting an error saying that `Output0Buffer` does not exist on the following lines:

```
    Output0Buffer.AddRow();
    Output0Buffer.Data = line;
    Output0Buffer.RegionName = regionName;
```

> Error CS0103  The name 'Output0Buffer' does not exist in the current context

What are we missing here?

Answer (score 16):

I found why that happened.
Basically, when creating the output, I changed its name explicitly to Output0Buffer and should have changed  `SynchronousInputID` property to "None".

That did the trick.

This can be done by:

- clicking on the `Script Transformation Editor`,
- clicking the catagory `Inputs and Outputs`,
- clicking on `Output 0`, and
- changing `SynchronousInputId` to `None` in the right hand panel:

[image]

Comment: It depends whether you want to create one line per inputline, or many.  If you want one line, then you the new columns are just part of the Input Columns, and there is no need for Output0Buffer.  If you want many, then this answer is correct.