# Combine 2 rows of CSV file in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, etl

I have one CSV file where the information is spread on two lines
Line 1 contains Name and age
Line 2 contains detail like address, city, salary, occupation

I want to combine 2 rows to insert it in a database.
CSV file :

```
Raju, 42
12345 west andheri,Mumbai, 100000, service
```

In SQL Server I can do by using cursor. But I have to do in SSIS.

Comment: Some options: 1. Write a script that removes the carriage return beforehand; 2. Use a script transform to transform it on the way in (like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31442325/ssis-combine-multiple-rows-into-single-row); 3. Use a lookup and SQL Command destination to insert the first row and update the second row. If any of these interest you I could explain further

Answer (score 0):

For a similar case, i will read each line as one column and use a script component to fix the structure. You can follow my answer on the following question. It contains a step-by-step guide:

- [SSIS reading LF as terminator when its set as CRLF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44164504/ssis-reading-lf-as-terminator-when-its-set-as-crlf/44218237#44218237)

Answer (score 0):

I like using a script component in order to be able to store data from a different row in this case.

1. Read the file as a single column CSV into Column1.
2. Add script component and add a new Output called CorrectedOutput and define all columns from both rows. Also, mark Column1 as read.
3. Create 2 variables outside of row processing to 'hold' first row

   ```
   string name = string.Empty;
   string Age = string.Empty;
   ```
4. Use a split to determine line 1 or line 2

   ```
   string[] str = Row.Column1.Split(',');
   ```
5. Use an if to determine row 1 or 2

   ```
   if(str.Length == 2)
   {
     name = str[0]; 
     age=str[1];}
   else
   {
        CorrectedOutputBuffer.AddRow();
        CorrectedOutputBuffer.Name = name; //This uses the stored value from prior row
        CorrectedOutputBuffer.Age = age; //This uses the stored value from prior row
        CorrectedOutputBuffer.Address = str[0];
        CorrectedOutputBuffer.City = str[1];
        CorrectedOutputBuffer.Salary = str[2];
        CorrectedOutputBuffer.Occupation = str[3];
   }
   ```

The overall effect is this...
On Row 1, you just hold the data in variables
On Row 2, you write out the data to 1 new row.